# Rundeck stop running steps based on global variable

Tags: rundeck

I have a Rundeck job that executes multiple steps, each of which are Job References to other small jobs. The first step selects a server to upgrade, and sets a global variable with the server name. The remaining steps perform upgrade tasks. It is possible though for the first step to return NONE as the server name, and if that's the case I would like to halt execution right there without running the remaining steps, and I'd like the whole job to be marked as Successful.

I could just make that first job exit with an error code, but then the whole job looks failed, and it looks like there is something wrong with it, even though it successfully ran and found there was nothing to upgrade.

Any ideas? I'm finding "use a flow control step" everywhere, but I can't see how to make that work for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

MegaDrive68k's answer is what you can do best with the basic opensource version or if you have the Enterprise version.

But you can also [create your own plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/tutorials/java-plugin.html) or make a fork out of an existing one.
Which I did with the official [flow control puglin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/flow-control-plugin) and add conditions.

You can fork this plugin and add in the java code 2 new @PluginProperty (That add two new field in a plugin parameter in rundeck interface) and make a comparison of values.

Example:

```java
    @PluginProperty(title = "First Value", description = "Compare this", required = true)
    String value1;
    @PluginProperty(title = "Second Value", description = "To this", required = true)
    String value2;
```

Comparison of Strings values (in your case it is)

```java
if (value1.equals(value2)) {...}
```

Comparison of Numeric values

```java
if (value1 == value2) {...}
```

If you want to stop the job with successful (it does not stop the parent job, just actual):

```java
context.getFlowControl().Halt(true);
```

If you want to stop the job with a failed status:

```java
context.getFlowControl().Halt(false);
```

If you want to stop the job with a customized status:

```java
context.getFlowControl().Halt("MY CUSTOM STATUS");
```

And finally, if you want to continue and not stop:

```java
context.getFlowControl().Continue();
```

So a complete example (add this to your public class):

```java
@PluginProperty(title = "First Value", description = "Compare this", required = true)
String value1;
@PluginProperty(title = "Second Value", description = "To this", required = true)
String value2;
@Override
public void executeStep(final PluginStepContext context, final Map<String, Object> configuration)
        throws StepException
{
    if (value1.equals(value2)) {
        //Halt actual JOB without failed
        context.getFlowControl().Halt(true);
    } else {
        //Continue
        context.getFlowControl().Continue();
    }
}
```

Then create your jar file and place it in the libext folder.

Now you can add your custom step. Put your global var in the first field and "NONE" in the second field.
If global var contain "NONE" the job stop successful at this step.

If you call a job with this step from oterh job (parent), the parent job continue.

If you want you can [use this fork plugin](https://github.com/Ookami-Git/conditional-flow-control-plugin) which already includes these modifications. [Look like this](https://i.imgur.com/5WGIxA0)

Comment: Very nice/insightful answer! Sometimes a little bit of code is more expressive of intent and easier to support in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to create complex workflows depending on some output value is to use the Ruleset Strategy (Rundeck Enterprise). Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/workflow-strategies/ruleset.html).

On the community version you can save the result of the first step on a key-value variable and do some "script-fu" in the following steps:

1. *Step 1:* print the status and save it on a data variable using the key-value data log filter.
2. *Steps 2,3,4:* capture the [key-value data](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/log-filters/key-value-data.html#key-value-data) and then the step can continue or not.

I made an example easy to [import](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions) to your instance for testing:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 27de501a-8bb2-4c6e-a5f9-0676e80ca75a
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - enforced: true
    name: opt1
    required: true
    value: 'true'
    values:
    - 'true'
    - 'false'
    valuesListDelimiter: ','
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo "url=${option.opt1}"
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'true'
            name: result
            regex: .*=\s*(.+)$
          type: key-value-data
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |-
        # data/value evaluation
        if [ "@data.result@" = "true" ]; then
            echo "step two"
        fi
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |-
        # data/value evaluation
        if [ "@data.result@" = "true" ]; then
            echo "step three"
        fi
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |-
        # data/value evaluation
        if [ "@data.result@" = "true" ]; then
            echo "step four"
        fi
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 27de501a-8bb2-4c6e-a5f9-0676e80ca75a
```

Comment: That looks great, thanks! One thing I'm not sure about -- if the remaining steps are job references, not scripts, I'm not sure how to wrap the variable evaluation around it to decide whether or not it should execute.

Comment: A good "trick" is to call those jobs directly in the bash inline-script using the API (via curl for example) or rd-cli (https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/). Greetings!